Illegal instruction while debugging void* function
I 've written this code to implement a BST:
a Node has 4 properties: 1 int val, 1 pointer to its parent, 1 pointer to its left child, 1 for right child. I write 2 methods: 1 for insertion and 1 for deletion.
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *parent;
    Node *left_child;
    Node *right_child;
    Node()
    {
        data = 0;
        parent = NULL;
        left_child = NULL;
        right_child = NULL;
    }
    Node(int val)
    {
        data = val;
        parent = NULL;
        left_child = NULL;
        right_child = NULL;
    }

    static void *insert(Node *current_node, int val)
    {
        if (current_node->data == val)
        {
            cout << "Duplicate Value";
            return NULL;
        }
        if (current_node->left_child == NULL && val < current_node->data)
        {
            Node *temp_node = new Node(val);
            current_node->left_child = temp_node;
            temp_node->parent = current_node;
            return NULL;
        }
        if (current_node->right_child == NULL && val > current_node->data)
        {
            Node *temp_node = new Node(val);
            current_node->right_child = temp_node;
            temp_node->parent = current_node;
            return NULL;
        }
        if (current_node->left_child != NULL && val < current_node->data)
        {
            return insert(current_node->left_child, val);
        }
        if (current_node->right_child != NULL && val > current_node->data)
        {
            return insert(current_node->right_child, val);
        }
    };

    static void *delete_node(Node *current_node, int val)
    {
        if (current_node == NULL)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else if (current_node->data == val)
        {
            if (current_node->left_child == NULL)
            {
                Node *parent_node = current_node->parent;
                if (parent_node->left_child == current_node)
                {
                    Node *right_child = current_node->right_child;
                    right_child->parent = parent_node;
                    parent_node->left_child = right_child;
                }
                else if (parent_node->right_child == current_node)
                {
                    Node *right_child = current_node->right_child;
                    right_child->parent = parent_node;
                    parent_node->right_child = right_child;
                }
            }
            else if (current_node->right_child == NULL)
            {
                Node *parent_node = current_node->parent;
                if (parent_node->left_child == current_node)
                {
                    Node *left_child = current_node->left_child;
                    left_child->parent = parent_node;
                    parent_node->left_child = left_child;
                }
                else if (parent_node->right_child == current_node)
                {
                    Node *left_child = current_node->left_child;
                    left_child->parent = parent_node;
                    parent_node->right_child = left_child;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (current_node->data > val)
        {
            delete_node(current_node->left_child, val);
        }
        else if (current_node->data < val)
        {
            delete_node(current_node->right_child, val);
        }
    };
};
int main()
{
    Node *root = new Node(4);
    Node::insert(root, 1);
    Node::insert(root, 2);
    Node::insert(root, 3);
    Node::insert(root, 5);
    Node::insert(root, 6);
    Node::delete_node(root, 10);
    Node::delete_node(root, 1);
    return 0;
}

But when i debug, it throw an exception "Illegal instruction" when hit line
delete_node(current_node->right_child, val);

after hit return nullptr;
I expect that method delete will delete descendant of current_node with value val using recursion.

why does insert have void* return type? Why is delete_node delcared to return void* too (but does not return anything) ?

flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning something is undefined behavior. Anything can happen

When you use your debugger, what does it tell you? Stepping through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values, and at the same time you draw and redraw the tree using pencil and paper, should help you quite a lot to understand what might be happening.

Side note : really don't use the first two lines of your code : #include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;. Your include is not standard C++, and using namespace std; is not recommended. Also do not use NULL but use nullptr

The compiler should have produced a warning "reaching the end of non-void function" on delete_node (since there's no return statement unless current_node == NULL). If it didn't, I suggest you find where to enable enough warnings that it does.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai sorry, my bad. At the begining, I declare it as class Node { //sthg }; static void *Node::insert(params){sthg}. Thanks for your help

Another side note : Also the use of a static function is not really a good design choice either. You miss a List class that can guarantee some invariances. You should add data to a list which leads to the creation of an internal node. e.g. Node& List::AddData(int)

For a better separation of concern and better code and design in general, separate data, node and tree into separate entities. If all you store is a plain int value, then that's okay to store directly in the node structure. But you should keep the node structure hidden behind the tree class. Users of your "tree" should not have to worry about individual nodes or how the tree is implemented or what it does. That also makes the code easier to test, debug and maintain.

@Someprogrammerdude yeah, it's only my dummy code to learn DSA and only myself work on it :=))))

Your code has undefined behaviour since it "falls of the end" of a function with a non-void return type  (returning void * is distinct from returning void).  Fix that first. and ensure a sensible pointer is always returned.  More generally, your code may have multiple  problems - an "illegal instruction" is a symptom of code molesting a pointer (e.g. dereferencing a null, using a pointer to something that no longer exists, etc) and there are many potential causes.  You really need to learn to use a debugger - to step through code and examine what effects each statement is having.

This kind of error accrues when control reaches end of function which should return something, but it doesn't. So when looking at your code I see that no condition from ifs is meet you reach end of function and there is not return statement, I recommend to add -Wall -extra -Werror to your build process to catch this kind of errors early. As point out in first comment, why your function has return type void * at all? Why not just void?

@MarekR at the begining, i write my code as Class Node{}; static void *Node::delete(){//implement}. Sorry about the mistake. I implement delete method directly in Node{} but doesn't remove the "*" notation. After i delete it, my code run as I eexpected.

@Nobody_left_behind this doesn't prove anything. Your code has Undefined Behavior. Design your API with annotation do not use return type if not required. Alos do as I recommended and add -Wall -Wextra -Werror to your compilation so 90% beginners errors are cough by compiler. https://godbolt.org/z/rYaoEvE7q

void* foo() { } is undefined behavior because it claims to return a void*, but doesn't return anything.  Your code has this problem.

Just declare 2 method:
static void insert()
static void delete()

Because these functions don't return anything

no. Thats not my answer. I posted a comment. And I didnt not suggest them to declare the methods like this.

insert does return something on some paths

@463035818_is_not_an_ai sorry, but your suggestion is helpful

it is not my suggestion. I merely asked why the return type of insert is void*. If it returns a  Node* I suggest to make that its return type, not void. Similar for delete, it does not return a void*. What I would suggest for both is to make them free functions.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai at the begining, i write my code as: Class Node{}; static void *Node::delete(){//implement}. Sorry about the mistake. I implement delete method directly in Node{} but doesn't remove the "*" notation. After i delete it, my code run as I eexpected.

insert is still broken. void* is the wrong return type, and it does not return on all paths.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
